# How to display big interactive map(or html) in PyQt6

Tags: pyqt6

## Current situation :

Polygon data was placed on top of the folium map. And I'm trying to display the map in pyqt6. However, it is not applicable when the data becomes large. Because "html_string" has a limit for 2MB.

```
       geojson_data = gdf.to_json()
        folium.GeoJson(geojson_data,
                       style_function=lambda x: {
                           'color': color_mapping.get(x['properties']['prt_type_nm'], 'gray')
                           }).add_to(m)

   
        html_string = m.get_root().render()
        self.web_view.setHtml(html_string)
```

## Here is source code :

https://github.com/1mwscode/pyqt6/blob/main/Maponly%40%40.py

## Tryed:

An error also occurs when saving html and loading it with an absolute path.

## Ultimately:

Ultimately, what I want is for the data to be displayed in real time as values are selected in the sidebar. So, I don't think it's a good option for me in terms of loading.

Please help in other ways.

Comment: Are you asking how to load more than 2mb of HTML, or alternative ways of updating the data? In the first case, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57260271). Note that questions should always be self-contained, not relying on external resources (especially if they are repositories, as their changes will make the question invalid). Please create a valid [mre] and include it in your question.