# Add a large shapefile to map in python using folium

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, shapefile, folium

I am displaying a folium map in my application using python, PyQt5 and Qt designer. Since there is no map widget in Qt designer, I add a general widget and then promote it to my custom map widget. It all works fine. Here is the python code for my promoted widget:

```
import io

import folium

from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class LeafWidget (QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        m = folium.Map(
            location=[40, -120] , zoom_start=10
        )
        self.view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
       
        data = io.BytesIO()
       
        m.save(data, close_file=False)
        self.view.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.show()
```

This works fine and I can see the map in my application.

I am also trying to display a GIS shapefile on top of this map. I have done some research and it seems like I cannot add GIS shapefile (.shp) directly to a folium map. So, I try to convert it to json first and then add the json on top of the map. I modified my code as below to add the .shp file to map:

```
import io

import folium
import os.path

from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets  import *
import geopandas as gpd

class LeafWidget (QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        m = folium.Map(
            location=[40, -120] , zoom_start=10
        )
        self.view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        # converting shp to geojson
        shp_file = gpd.read_file('input/2015_loaded_NoCC.shp')
        shp_file.to_file('myshpfile.json', driver='GeoJSON')
        shp = os.path.join('', 'myshpfile.json')
        data = io.BytesIO()
        folium.GeoJson(shp).add_to(m)
        m.save(data, close_file=False)
        self.view.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.show()
```

but now my map doesn't show up at all. It's just an empty space with no errors in the console or error log. If I save the map as an HTML file using "m.save('map.html')" though, it does save the file and when I open it, it displays the json file on the map, but for some reason, the way I am doing it to show the map in my application is not working after adding the shp-->json file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in these questions([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57260271/6622587) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48926971/6622587)) and in [the official docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#setHtml):

> **void QWebEnginePage::setHtml(const QString &html, const QUrl &baseUrl
> = QUrl())**
>  Sets the content of this page to html. baseUrl is optional and used to resolve relative URLs in the document, such as referenced
> images or stylesheets.
>
> The html is loaded immediately; external objects are loaded
> asynchronously.
>
> If a script in the html runs longer than the default script timeout
> (currently 10 seconds), for example due to being blocked by a modal
> JavaScript alert dialog, this method will return as soon as possible
> after the timeout and any subsequent html will be loaded
> asynchronously.
>
> When using this method, the web engine assumes that external
> resources, such as JavaScript programs or style sheets, are encoded in
> UTF-8 unless otherwise specified. For example, the encoding of an
> external script can be specified through the charset attribute of the
> HTML script tag. It is also possible for the encoding to be specified
> by the web server.
>
> This is a convenience function equivalent to setContent(html,
> "text/html", baseUrl).
>
> Note: This method will not affect session or global history for the
> page.
>
> Warning: This function works only for HTML, for other mime types (such
> as XHTML and SVG) setContent() should be used instead.
>
> **Warning: The content will be percent encoded before being sent to the
> renderer via IPC. This may increase its size. The maximum size of the
> percent encoded content is 2 megabytes minus 30 bytes.**

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

`setHtml()` does not support content greater than 2MB, so in your particular case there are 2 solutions:

- Save the folium map in an html file:

  ```py
  import io
  import os

  from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


  CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


  class LeafWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

          self.view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()

          shp_filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "input", "2015_loaded_NoCC.shp")
          shp_file = gpd.read_file(shp_filename)
          shp_file_json_str = shp_file.to_json()

          m = folium.Map(location=[40, -120], zoom_start=10)
          folium.GeoJson(shp_file_json_str).add_to(m)

          tmp_file = QtCore.QTemporaryFile("XXXXXX.html", self)
          if tmp_file.open():
              m.save(tmp_file.fileName())
              url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(tmp_file.fileName())
              self.view.load(url)

          lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
          lay.addWidget(self.view)


  def main():
      app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
      w = LeafWidget()
      w.show()
      app.exec_()


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
  ```
- Use a QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler to return the html:

  **qfolium.py**

  ```py
  import json
  import io

  from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWebEngineCore, QtWebEngineWidgets


  class FoliumSchemeHandler(QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler):
      def __init__(self, app):
          super().__init__(app)
          self.m_app = app

      def requestStarted(self, request):
          url = request.requestUrl()
          name = url.host()
          m = self.m_app.process(name, url.query())
          if m is None:
              request.fail(QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineUrlRequestJob.UrlNotFound)
              return
          data = io.BytesIO()
          m.save(data, close_file=False)
          raw_html = data.getvalue()
          buf = QtCore.QBuffer(parent=self)
          request.destroyed.connect(buf.deleteLater)
          buf.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
          buf.write(raw_html)
          buf.seek(0)
          buf.close()
          request.reply(b"text/html", buf)


  class FoliumApplication(QtCore.QObject):
      scheme = b"folium"

      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          super().__init__(parent)
          scheme = QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineUrlScheme(self.scheme)
          QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineUrlScheme.registerScheme(scheme)
          self.m_functions = dict()

      def init_handler(self, profile=None):
          if profile is None:
              profile = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineProfile.defaultProfile()
          handler = profile.urlSchemeHandler(self.scheme)
          if handler is not None:
              profile.removeUrlSchemeHandler(handler)

          self.m_handler = FoliumSchemeHandler(self)
          profile.installUrlSchemeHandler(self.scheme, self.m_handler)

      def register(self, name):
          def decorator(f):
              self.m_functions[name] = f
              return f

          return decorator

      def process(self, name, query):
          f = self.m_functions.get(name)
          if f is None:
              print("not found")
              return

          items = QtCore.QUrlQuery(query).queryItems()
          params_json = dict(items).get("json", None)
          if params_json is not None:
              return f(**json.loads(params_json))
          return f()

      def create_url(self, name, params=None):
          url = QtCore.QUrl()
          url.setScheme(self.scheme.decode())
          url.setHost(name)
          if params is not None:
              params_json = json.dumps(params)
              query = QtCore.QUrlQuery()
              query.addQueryItem("json", params_json)
              url.setQuery(query)
          return url
  ```

  **main.py**

  ```py
  import io
  import os

  import folium

  from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
  import geopandas as gpd

  from qfolium import FoliumApplication


  CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

  folium_app = FoliumApplication()


  @folium_app.register("load_shapefile")
  def load_shapefile(latitude, longitude, zoom_start, shp_filename):
      shp_file = gpd.read_file(shp_filename)
      shp_file_json_str = shp_file.to_json()

      m = folium.Map(
          location=[latitude, longitude], zoom_start=zoom_start
      )
      folium.GeoJson(shp_file_json_str).add_to(m)
      print(m)
      return m


  class LeafWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

          self.view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()

          lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
          lay.addWidget(self.view)

          self.resize(640, 480)

          shp_filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "input", "2015_loaded_NoCC.shp")

          params = {
              "shp_filename": shp_filename,
              "latitude": 40,
              "longitude": -120,
              "zoom_start": 5,
          }
          url = folium_app.create_url("load_shapefile", params=params)
          self.view.load(url)


  def main():
      app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
      folium_app.init_handler()
      w = LeafWidget()
      w.show()
      app.exec_()


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
  ```

Comment: wow. Thanks for this answer. I used your first solution since it is easier for me to understand.. You are amazing!